# Specificity when redirecting dynamic PHP urls via htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm changing a site layout from example.com/product.php?id=1 to example.com/new.php

I need to leave a rule for 301 redirect for this redirection from id=1 to new.php.

What I have, that WORKS currently

```
RewriteCond %{query_string} id=1
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/new.php? [R=301,L]
```

**Problem Needs Solving:**

There is also a page called example.com/other-products.php?id=1

All the products on this OTHER page are ALSO being redirected to 'new.php'.

**Final Question:**

How can I apply specificity to this redirect such that only dynamic urls that are preceded by products.php are redirected and all other dynamic urls on the site with identical id number (e.g. id=1) stay put?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use more than one condition. Maybe something using `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` to check the page. All previous conditions must match in order for the rule to run. Or even just add the page name to the rule instead of `(.*)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use correct URI pattern in `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{query_string} ^id=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^product\.php$ https://example.com/new.php? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Take note of `RewriteRule ^product\.php$`, which will only affect `/product.php?id=1` URL but won't affect `/product-abc.php?id=1` OR `/product.php?id=123`

Comment: This is the solution. I have entered it into the site, tested, and it has worked flawlessly. I will accept as answer when the timer allows. Thank you good sir! You are very helpful for me.